# Is there a way to ignore Visual Studio errors thrown by XAML?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, fonts, app.xaml

I know you can do it in CodeBehind with something like this...

```
#pragma warning disable 67
...
#pragma warning restore 67
```

But is there a way to do this type of thing in XAML?

For example, I have the following in my App.xaml...

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ExtendedFontFamily">Verdana</FontFamily>
```

And it keeps throwing me these VS errors (even though it builds successfully)...

> Error 1   Type 'FontFamily' is not
>   usable as an object element because it
>   is not public or does not define a
>   public parameterless constructor or a
>   type
>   converter.    C:\Users\jed.hunsaker\Documents\Work\NextGen\src\ESO.App.Reporting\ESO.App.Reporting.UI.Silverlight\App.xaml    8   4   ESO.App.Reporting.UI.Silverlight

and...

> Error 2   The type 'FontFamily' does not
>   support direct
>   content.  C:\Users\jed.hunsaker\Documents\Work\NextGen\src\ESO.App.Reporting\ESO.App.Reporting.UI.Silverlight\App.xaml    8   42  ESO.App.Reporting.UI.Silverlight

Unless you guys know a better way to store a FontFamily in your App.xaml, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a resource dictionary. Here is an example:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <FontFamily x:Key="ExtendedFontFamily">Verdana</FontFamily>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And you should reference in you App.xaml like so (assuming they are in a Resources folder):

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.App"
                >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Fonts.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```